# Alternatives to automatically images + HTML signatures with body text in emails

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I've done a fair bit of research on this topic and I've come to the conclusion that what I'm looking to do is just simply not possible. No matter what method is used from the Outlook object library; it seems that any signature that is automatically populated by functions like .display and .getInspector will always be wiped when .body, .HTMLBody, or .RTFBody are also called afterwards. I've gotten a lot of great advice such as below but it seems like any variation of .body will wipe the signature no matter how the signature is populated.

```
    Dim OutApp          As Object
    Dim OutMail         As Object
    Dim signature       As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp.Session.Logon
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail                               
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML                      
        .HTMLBody = "f"
        .Display
    End With

    signature = OutMail.HTMLBody
```

I've been thinking lately, would it be possible to take the .htm signature file located in \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signature and render that into the email itself by including it in .body? Does anyone know of any alternatives to using .display and .getInspector to input a signature?

Edit 2:

```
Dim OutApp          As Object
Dim OutMail         As Object
Dim signature       As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
OutMail.Display
signature = OutMail.HTMLBody

With OutMail
    .HTMLBody = "fdA" & signature
    '.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The body is wiped out because your code explicitly wipes it out. Or, in your particular case, Outlook never applies the signature because it sees that the HTML body was previously set.

Outlook will add the signature when you call `Display` or `GetInspector`. In your case, call `Display` first (at this point the signature is added), then read the `HTMLBody` property (it will now contain the signature). Merge it with your html body (note that two HTML strings cannot be simply concatenated, you must merge them), then set the HTMLBody property back.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by reading and then merging HTMLBody. Please see my edit above. By reading, do you mean to store the HTML signature within a variable and then setting the HTMLBody property equal to the content of the email and the signature variable?

Comment: No, read the value of the HTMLBody property (it will now contain the signature), find the position of the "`<body`" substring. Find the next occurrence of "`>`" (this way you can take care of the "body" tags with attributes). Then insert your HTML body after that "`>`" substring. Now set the combined string to the `HTMLBody` property.